# Error in mysql driver: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to insert data in my database, but I'm getting this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

here's my jsp file for inserting data in database.

insert.jsp

```
<%@page import = "java.io.*, java.sql.*, java.util.*"%>
<%@page import = "javax.servlet.http.*, javax.servlet.*"%>

<%
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbmembers";
Connection connection = null;
PrepareStatament pstatement = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

int updateQuery = 0;
if (name!=null && email!=null && uname!=null && pass!=null) {
    if (name!="" && email!="uname" && pass!="") {
        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root","");
            String queryString = "INSERT INFO tablemem (Name, Email, Uname, Pass) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            pstatememt = connection.preparedStatement (queryString);
            pstatement.setString(1, name);
            pstatement.setString(2, email);
            pstatement.setString(3, uname);
            pstatement.setString(4, pass);
            updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();

            if (updateQuery != 0) { %>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Successfully Registered</th>
                        <th><a href="login.jsp">Login here</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <%
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.println("Unable to connect to Database");
        }

        finally {
            pstatement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
%>
```

I've already:

- place the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar` in WEB-INF/lib
- added the jar file in eclipse
- set the classpath for mysql

But I'm still getting the same error. Did I missed something?

Comment: Unrelated, don't put Java code in JSP (use servlet controllers) and don't use DriverManager (use proper DataSource).

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have added the connector jar file into the build path
 to do so right click on the jar file and click add to build path